# How to get computer speak name of images picked at random correcltly

Tags: javascript, html, image, speech-synthesis

I have a question and need help please. I have a Codepen page that I partially created already, see below link sample, where 4 random shapes show up on screen, and when clicked move to the next one. The shapes are Square, Triangle, Circle or Cross.

I can get the images to change but i don't know how to link the names to the shape correctly and for the computer to speak it? i.e image of square and computer says square, next picture of Triangle and computer says triangle etc, etc.

SAMPLE I made to do this with random colors https://codepen.io/3DAttic/pen/gOrrQzq correctly, but harder with images.

**Codepen page I need help on https://codepen.io/3DAttic/pen/vYGpWOx**

```
     'HTML'
     <body onkeydown="speakPrevious()"
      onkeyup="getNewRandomImage()">
     <p> <b>This webpage will show 4 shapes, Circle, Triangle, Cross, or Square, one at a time and in random order.
<U>You MAY see the same shape several times in a row.</U>
This is expected behaviour and <U>NOT</U> a fault.</U> </p>
<p>Click or touch on the shape to move to the next one.</b></p> 

<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000" LINK="#FF0000" VLINK="#000080" ALINK="#000080"    onLoad="pickimg()">
    <body onLoad="pickimg()">
   <a href="" onClick="pickimg();return false;"><center><IMG SRC="YOUR IMAGE" width=325px   name="randimg" border=0></a></body>

   'JS'
        const page = document.querySelector("body");
        page.addEventListener("click", function () {
        speakPrevious();
     });
       function speakPrevious() {
       var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
       var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(window.value);
       synth.speak(utterThis);
     }
       function pickimg(){
       var imagenumber = 4 ;
     //change above number as you increase shapes
       var randomnumber = Math.random() ;
       var rand1 = Math.round( (imagenumber-1) * randomnumber) + 1;
       images = new Array
       images[1] = "https://i.ibb.co/qrNQcfd/circle.png"
       images[2] = "https://i.ibb.co/x26Bhsw/triangle.png"
       images[3] = "https://i.ibb.co/DzCjnXx/cross.png"
       images[4] = "https://i.ibb.co/bQ3ndHY/square.png"
        //images[5] = "https://i.ibb.co/cNkZ48H/star.png"
       var image = images[rand1]
       document.randimg.src = image
      }
 //End

//Sample used to have speach attached https://codepen.io/3DAttic/pen/gOrrQzq
    speakPrevious();
    function speakPrevious() {
    var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
    var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(window.value);
    synth.speak(utterThis);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes, the biggest was to convert the array to an object containing both the shapes' names and their image URLs. Then Object.keys and Object.values make arrays of the names and URLs and the random number picks the appropriate ones.

```js
const images = {
  circle: 'https://i.ibb.co/qrNQcfd/circle.png',
  triangle: 'https://i.ibb.co/x26Bhsw/triangle.png',
  cross: 'https://i.ibb.co/DzCjnXx/cross.png',
  square: 'https://i.ibb.co/bQ3ndHY/square.png',
  //star: 'https://i.ibb.co/cNkZ48H/star.png'
};

function pickimg(){
  const imagenumber = Object.keys(images).length;
  const randomnumber = Math.random() ;
  const randomNo = Math.round( (imagenumber-1) * randomnumber);

  const imageSrc = Object.values(images)[randomNo];
  randimg.src = imageSrc;
  return Object.keys(images)[randomNo];
}

let shape = pickimg();

const page = document.querySelector("body");

page.addEventListener("click", function () {
  speakPrevious(shape);
});

page.addEventListener('keydown', () => {shape = pickimg()});
page.addEventListener('keyup', () => {speakPrevious(shape)});

randimg.addEventListener('click', () => {shape = pickimg()});

function speakPrevious(txt) {
  var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
  var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(txt);
  synth.speak(utterThis);
}

//End
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div><b><p>This webpage will show 4 shapes, Circle, Triangle, Cross, or Square, one at a time and in random order.
    <U>You MAY see the same shape several times in a row.</U>
  This is expected behaviour and <U>NOT</U> a fault.</U> </p>
  <p>Click or touch on the shape to move to the next one.</p></b></div> 

<IMG SRC="YOUR IMAGE" width=325px id="randimg" border=0>
```

Other changes:

- remove all javascript from the html and put it into the JS.
- remove some styling and put it into CSS; you could also do the same
  for bold and underlined.
- You can use an array's .length property, instead of updating a number of shapes manually. Thus using Object.keys(images).length will always give the current number of shapes.
- Various other changes - ask if you want clarification.

Comment: Frazer, this is fantastic, Thank You, one minor change, I would like is the name of the shape to be spoken when you click and it moves to the next shape i.e calls the previous shapes name and not when the current picture. I had the speakPrevious in my example, onkeydown="speakPrevious()" can this be added so it the same. I see it in the JS code but it does not seems to work on that?
One extra thing can it work by clicking anywhere on the page and not just on the image? if you click outside the image it speaks the name of the shape and does not move?

Comment: Yes all that is possible. Of course there's a difference between helping someone out and doing their programming for them. Maybe try an online course like codeacademy, for example?

Comment: Thanks Frazer, i appriecate the comment, everything is possible but sometimes being shown makes the learning easier. I've taken what you did and used it already this is just small addition. most of the code is already present, any pointers would be helpful.